# List all of the donors who have donated a total amount greater than something

Tags: sql, oracle

This is table structure

Donor (**donorID**, name)

Donation (**ID**, donorID, amount)

Here is my query :

```
SELECT donor.name, SUM(donation.amount) "Total"
FROM donor, donation
WHERE donor.donorID = donation.donorID
AND SUM(donation.amount) > 1000;
GROUP BY donor.name
ORDER BY SUM(donation.amount) DESC;
```

Here is the error:

> ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
>   00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"

There is not error when i remove the sum(donation) < 1000
How do i integrate it without error? Please help.

Comment: Use `Having Sum(donation.amount) > 1000`

Comment: AND SUM(donation.amount) > 1000; remove ; at the end of this line (or it's just a typo?)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot put an aggregation function in the `where` clause.  You need a `having` clause:

```
SELECT donor.name, SUM(donation.amount) "Total"
FROM donor, donation
WHERE donor.donorID = donation.donorID
GROUP BY donor.name
HAVING SUM(donation.amount) > 1000
ORDER BY SUM(donation.amount) DESC;
```

However, you should learn to use proper `join` syntax and table aliases:

```
SELECT d.name, SUM(dn.amount) as "Total"
FROM donor d JOIN
     donation dn
     ON d.donorID = dn.donorID
GROUP BY d.name
HAVING SUM(dn.amount) > 1000
ORDER BY SUM(dn.amount) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure why using "having" is the correct way, there were cases when using my method works too except for this example, any clearer example on when to use having?

Comment: You always use having when you are filtering on an aggregation function such as `SUM()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a HAVING clause like so:

```
SELECT donor.name, SUM(donation.amount) "Total"
FROM donor, donation
WHERE donor.donorID = donation.donorID
GROUP BY donor.name
HAVING SUM(donation.amount) > 1000
ORDER BY SUM(donation.amount) DESC;
```

Also, as Marc B pointed out, the semi-colon is in an incorrect place terminating the query.

Answer (score -1):

Typo:

```
AND SUM(donation.amount) > 1000;
                               ^---terminates query
GROUP BY donor.name
```

`group by` is not a valid way to start a new query.